# rails nested forms and building multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `property model` that `has_many units`.  Each unit `has_one cost` and each unit also `has_one interior_amenity`.  When the `new property form` is loaded I want to build the fields for the nested form, but only some fields are showing.

I want to have the new property form `app/views/properties/_form` display fields for `cost` and `interior_amenity` which belong_to unit.

The property form has nested fields for units.  The units then have nested fields for cost and interior_amenity

I've tried building the associations in `properties_controller#new` but I can't get both the cost and interior_amenity to show at the same time.

```
  # GET /properties/new
  def new
    @property = Property.new
    # nested fields won't initially show on the property form unless build is called here

    # chaining units and costs work but then I can't add the interior_amenity 
    @property.units.build.build_cost
    
    # the form will fail when I do this
    @property = @property.units.build
    @property.build_cost
    @property.build_interior_amenity

 
    # this causes 2 sets of unit fields to be added to the form 
    @property.units.build.build_cost
    @property.units.build.build_interior_amenity

  end
```

property model

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :units, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

unit model

```
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property

  has_one :cost, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :interior_amenity, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cost, allow_destroy: true  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interior_amenity, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

cost model

```
class Cost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

interior_amenity model

```
class InteriorAmenity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

Comment: You just need to "capture" the built unit in a local variable so that you can build the other 2 associations e.g. `unit = @property.units.build; unit.build_cost; unit.build_interior_amenity` should work just fine.

Comment: that worked.  thanks!